# Remover um elemento especifico do array javascript

Tags: javascript

Bom estou precisando remover um elemento do array pelo índice, por exemplo:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Ao remover o elemento de índice 3:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
```

É necessário que ele remova tudo apos o índice informado inclusive o índice.

Tentei fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
    var localUltimo = w_history.length - 1;
    var anterior = w_history[localUltimo];
    // var ultimo = w_history.pop();
    for(var i = 0; i < w_history.length; i++){
        console.log("tam " + w_history[i] + " ultm " + anterior);
        if(w_history[i] == anterior){
            w_fim = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log("w_fim " + w_fim);
    console.log("tamanho " + w_history.length);

    while(w_history.lenght > w_fim){
        console.log("w_fim " + w_fim);
        console.log("tamanho " + w_history.length);
        w_history.pop();
    }
    var ref = w_history[localUltimo - 1];
    console.log("ref " + ref)
    activate_page(ref, '1');
    w_history.slice(0, ref)
    console.log(w_history);
```

Porém o resultado não foi satisfatório ao executar ele acrescenta um elemento `undefined` e logo após limpa todo array:

ARRAY ANTES:

```
["#login", "#listar_CELULAS", "#minha_CELULAS", #listar_CELULAS]
```

ARRAY DEPOIS:

```
["#login", "#listar_CELULAS", "#minha_CELULAS", "#listar_CELULAS", "#minha_CELULAS"]
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Você quer remover o elemento de índice 3 e todos os posteriores?

Comment: Exatamente, é isto que preciso

Comment: Seria complicado por o array real, antes e depois?

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: Desculpe Renan ainda nao entendi o que quer, o que compreendi é que você remover o primeiro elemento e concatenou o array com o proprio array sem o primeiro elemento

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Como o Pedro Camara respondeu você pode utilizar o método slice, entretanto este método não remove elementos do array original e sim retorna um novo array com os elementos especificados pelos parametros start e end. Existe um outro método chamado splice que remove/adiciona elementos no array original e também retorna os elementos removidos. No metodo splice você especifica o indice inicial e a quantidade de elementos a serem removidos incluindo o elemento do indice inicial.

```
var test = [1, 2, 3, 4];
test.splice(2, 1);
```

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 8):

Você pode utilizar o método [slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp).

- Os parâmetros são o índice inicial e o índice final que você deseja
- O método retorna um novo array com os elementos selecionados
- Os elementos selecionados serão os que estiverem no índice inicial até o indíce final, porém o elemento no indíce final não será incluído
- O array original não será alterado.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var novoArr = arr.slice(2, 5);
console.log('Array original: ' + arr);
console.log('Novo array: ' + novoArr);
```

Comment: Eu ia mesmo comentar isso

Comment: Não está funcionando para mim, ele apenas acrescenta um elemento undefined >["#login", "#listar_CELULAS", "#minha_CELULAS", undefined, undefined] ionic_subpage.js:39
["#login", "#listar_CELULAS", "#minha_CELULAS", undefined, undefined]

Comment: Conseguir resolver meu problema, so que ele não está cortando está adicionando apenas

Comment: O que você quis dizer com cortando apenas @RenanRodrigues? Editei a resposta atribuindo o novo array ao anterior.

Answer (score 5):

Tal como eu explico em meu vídeo sobre *[Como Remover Elementos de Vetores em JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6fKHK0yg3X4)* e também como outros usuários já responderam, basicamente você pode utilizar a função `Array.splice(indice, quantidade)` passando como parâmetro o `índice` à partir do qual você deseja iniciar a remoção de elementos do vetor e a `quantidade` de elementos que você deseja remover.

Após ser executada, a função `Array.splice` irá modificar o vetor original removendo os elementos solicitados e irá também retornar um novo vetor contendo os elementos que foram removidos.

**Exemplo**:

```
var vetor = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var elementosRemovidos = vetor.splice(1, 2); // Remove o segundo e terceiro elementos do vetor.

console.log(elementosRemovidos); // ["B", "C"]
console.log(vetor); // ["A", "D", "E"]
```

Answer (score -2):

é só uma o metodo splice amigo e muito simples.
No splice basta colocar o valor index da posição do elemento no array e quantos elementos após ele voce quer retirar, caso seja apenas 1 elemento basta color o numeor 1 no segundo

remover o elemento numero 4

let arrayNumeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

lembrando que a contagem em array começa no index 0
arrayNumeros.splice(3,1)

console.log(arrayNumeros )
[1,2,3,5,6,7]

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).